# Mongodb Aggregating information into new collection automatically?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement this.

If I have one large collection in my mongodb that holds all of my "Inventory" information for my warehouse without regard to the specific "type" of inventory, what is the best way to aggregate the data into their own collections continuously? **Added this information after-the-fact: I'm using a Mean stack so maybe some of this is better to just do server-side with an angular function rather than actually keeping a collection updated?

For instance, my current "Inventory" collection would have items such as

- _id: something, name: item1, type: chemical, vendor: something, safetycode: ####, machineUse: n/a, equipmentUse: n/a ...
- _id: something2, name: item2, type: machine, vendor: something2 safetycode: n/a, machineUse: "digging", equipmentUse: n/a ...
- _id: something3, name: item3, type: equipment, vendor: something3 safetycode: n/a, machineUse: n/a, equipmentUse: "Computer" ...

I'm inclined to $group but is this best practice to keep a 'SEPERATE' collection updated with their respective groups? You'll notice in the following that the aggregate function should collect the specific 'type'(Chemical, Machine, equipment, etc...) and store all the details of each item collected with fields that are only used for that 'type' (i.e, Chemicals use 'safetycode', machines DO NOT use saftey code so it's left out and instead 'machineUse' is stored, etc.)

```
 db.invfulls.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
                "_id": "$itype",
                "total": {$sum : 1},
                "items":{
                    "$push":{
                        "$cond":{ 
                            "if": {"$eq":["$itype","Chemical"]}, 
                            "then": {"id":"$_id", "name":"$name", "vendor":"$vendor", "review":"$needsreview"},
                            "else": {"id":"$_id", "name":"$name", "vendor":"$vendor"}
                        }
                        }
  }
  }},
    {$out: "invByType"}
])
```

Additionally, would I have to make this a function in the database and call that function anytime there is a new "post" made?

I've read a bit about the mapReduce as well but everything I read says it's a very slow and shouldn't be used?

Comment: You are misinterpreting a whole topic. When we talk about "pre-aggregation" it actually means no involvement of the aggregation framework whatsoever. Instead we use "upsert" operations and `$inc` and similar modifiers to "aggregate" data as we write it. Also the `$out` stage of aggregation pipelines creates a "new" collection every time it is invoked, so you cannot "collect" data in this way, nor is is basically practical to "trigger" results in data changes. At a very basic level ["views"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) are more suited to what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow your statements Neal, i'm sorry! I understand how $upsert/$inc/$out work and when to use them. So, i'm assuming you're saying I shouldn't take this route and instead just aggregate the information once (right now) and then use that new document to store future information when it's already aggregated, rather than having to use $out to "update" a collection anytime there is a change in the database. This way using functions like $upsert will take care of the creating/updating the record. Correct?